# To upload JSON data from flutter app to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have developed an app while currently sending JSON data to AWS gateway -> AWS lambda, where my API is hosted. However, I got to know about the size limit with Lambda hence I am trying an alternate way to directly upload that JSON data to the AWS S3 bucket in JSON file format and then trigger a Lambda function for that file. However, I was not able to find any solution to upload that data to S3 (tries, AWS amplify, S3 Http etc.) Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have the backend create a presigned URL, and the application can [use that URL to upload an object to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/S3OutpostsPresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anon said, you can generate a PreSigned URL on the backend and send it back to the frontend to upload the file. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/.

If you want to process that file once it is uploaded you can use [S3 Event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html) and react to `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`. The target of that can be a Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks. I also got the solution from Chatgpt and it worked. issue solved